# iterating over two dataframes at the same time with if statement

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

i have two dataframes, i wanna iterate through the first one, and if a condition is checked, I move to the second dataframe and see if another condition is checked (in the same rowxcolumn as the first dataframe)

this would be dataframe 1

| id | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | XY00 | AB80 | XY01 |
| 1 | FY34 | XY60 | XY91 |
| 2 | AB46 | AC40 | NY23 |
| 3 | XY70 | AB23 | DG60 |

this would be dataframe 2, they have the same id and idx, but different column names, although the same length

| id | e1 | e2 | e3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2003-12-09 | 2005-01-01 | 2006-12-14 |
| 1 | 2004-11-09 | 2002-01-01 | 1999-07-10 |
| 2 | 2012-02-13 | 2011-08-22 | 2003-03-16 |
| 3 | 2003-01-17 | 2005-01-01 | 2017-09-30 |

the ideal output would be

| id | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | XY00 | AB80 | XY01 |
| 3 | XY70 | AB23 | DG60 |

so only the values from dataframe 1 that start with 'XY' and that are older than '2003-01-01' in the corresponding column in dataframe 2

i try this for loop, but it outputs an empty dataframe

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns = df1.columns)

for ind, row in df1.iterrows():
    if ((ind,row) == ("XY00")):
        for ind2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
             if((ind2,row2) >= ("2003-01-01")):
                    new_df = new_df.append(row)
```

Comment: Iterating over individual rows is often bad practice in `pandas`. Can you please edit your question and put there input dataframe (small) and expected output?

Comment: i just edited it,

Comment: Why in the final dataframe is row with `AB46 AC40 NY23`? The values don't begin with `XY`?

Comment: ah yes sorry, i just notice, i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that avoids using iterating over values.

check for values that start with XY

```
d1 = df1.stack().str.startswith('XY').unstack()
```

check for date values that are after `2003-01-01`. If dataframe already contains all datetime dtypes,`.apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')` can be removed from below.

```
d2 = df2.apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce').set_axis(df1.columns,axis=1).gt(pd.to_datetime('2003-01-01'))
```

Find where at least one value in each row in both dataframes are `True`

```
m = (d1 & d2).any(axis=1)
```

Use the above to filter the original `df1`

```
filtered_df = df1.loc[m]
```

Output:

```
       1     2     3
id                  
0   XY00  AB80  XY01
3   XY70  AB23  DG60
```

Comment: when i run the [d2 = df2.apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce').set_axis(df1.columns,axis=1).gt(pd.to_datetime('2003-01-01'))
] it gives me this error: 'Length mismatch: Expected axis has 429 elements, new values have 215 elements', do you know how to get around that error? 215 is the number of columns I have in every dataframe

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
#df1=df1.set_index('id')
#df2=df2.set_index('id')

final=df1.merge(df2,left_index=True, right_index=True) #merge df1 and df2 on index
print(final)
'''
      1     2     3         e1         e2         e3
0  XY00  AB80  XY01 2003-12-09 2005-01-01 2006-12-14
1  FY34  XY60  XY91 2004-11-09 2002-01-01 1999-07-10
2  AB46  AC40  NY23 2012-02-13 2011-08-22 2003-03-16
3  XY70  AB23  DG60 2003-01-17 2005-01-01 2017-09-30
'''

dictionary = dict(zip(df1.columns, df2.columns)) #I'm converting the columns to a dictonary to be key-value.
print(dictionary)
'''
{'1': 'e1', '2': 'e2', '3': 'e3'}
'''
```

Now i loop through the specified conditions for each column matches and save it in a list. I'm converting this list of dataframes to a single dataframe with concat.

```
df = pd.concat([final[(final[k].str.contains('XY')) & (final[v] >= '2003-01-01')] for k,v in dictionary.items()]).drop_duplicates()
df = df[df1.columns]
print(df)
'''
    1         2      3
0   XY00    AB80    XY01
3   XY70    AB23    DG60

'''
```

Comment: when i run this code "df = pd.concat([final[(final[k].str.contains('XY')) & (final[v] >= '2003-01-01')] for k,v in dictionary.items()]).drop_duplicates()" it gives this error 'KeyError: 'Iid'', do you have an idea of what that could mean?

Comment: id columns must be indexes. if not, use the code in the comment line in my answer.

Comment: i set that column to index, now it s displaying the same error but with the following column, Keyerror: '1'

Comment: Can you share output of this: `print(dict(zip(df1.columns, df2.columns)))`

Comment: the output is very long since the data is very big, but in the example above, it is the equivalent of {'id' : '1', 'id' : 'e1', '2' : 'e2', '3' : 'e3'} for all columns

Comment: Id columns are still not indexes. If they were index they would not appear in this dictionary. I say again, convert the id columns to index. How to do this is at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: you should also use the set_index function at the very beginning of the code. then you can use merge and converting to dictionary.